# Bearer error="invalid_token" from .net core 2.0

Tags: php, .net-core, jwt

I have an authentication system set up in PHP that I am trying to use to send JSON Web Tokens to a client app in order for the app to access a .net core 2.0 api.  So the authentication server takes user credentials and if the credentials pass, it generates the token using a public/private key pair I created with openssl.  I am generating the token using the procedure here: http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/security/using-a-json-web-token-in-php.html

I can decode the resulting token with jwt.io just fine.  The decoded version looks like this:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256"
}

{
  "iss": "https://crm.advtis.com",
  "exp": "2017-12-21 18:14:42",
  "aud": "https://localhost:44354",
  "data": {
    "username": "pwalter@advtis.com",
    "role": 1
  }
}
```

I can enter the string from my private key file, which was used to encode the token, and jwt.io says the signature is valid.

So now I want to send the token along with a request to my API to gain access to that resource, which while debugging is found on localhost.  Here is the .NET 2.0 startup code relevant to that:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<SmartRxDBContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Audience = "https://localhost:44354/";
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "https://crm.advtis.com/",
                    IssuerSigningKey = new X509SecurityKey(new X509Certificate2("C:\\Path\\To\\webOrders-cert-AspNetPubkey.cert"))
                };
            });
            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

The path referenced is to a pem formatted public key I generated, also using openssl, from the private key used to encode the jwt.  I was trying to follow this example for the .NET Core piece - [JWT Validation and Authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/)
 - but of course the whole auth middleware configuration has been moved in 2.0 to the ConfigureServices method, and there is no longer an AutomaticAuthorization option.

Everything seems to be fine, but I am getting a 401 - Unauthorized Bearer error="invalid_token" error when making a request with the header as `Authorization: Bearer TOKEN` Anyway, I was hoping someone could give me some advice as to where I might be going wrong and/or how I could troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got this figured out for anyone wanting to run this same type of scenario.

My first problem was that I was using HMAC to generate the tokens on the PHP side.  HMAC is not a public/private pair algorithm.  I installed the [firebase/php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) library with composer, and used that to generate my token like this:

```
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
$token = array(      
"iss" => "https://crm.advtis.com",
"exp" => time()+10000,
"aud" => "https://localhost:44354",
"data" => array(
    "username" => "pwalter@advtis.com",
    "role" => 1
)
);

$jwt = JWT::encode($token, file_get_contents("../path/to/private.key"), 'RS256');
```

The key file was generated on the command line with OpenSSL.  I used the same utility to generate a public key with the private key.  Both files are in PEM format.

The next thing I had to do was get the public key into .NET.  The easiest way I found to do use an RSACryptoServiceProvider, sort of like this:

```
private static RSACryptoServiceProvider myRSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        JwtHelper.FromXmlString(myRSA, "C:\\Users\\Path\\To\\xmlPubKey.xml");
        services.AddDbContext<SmartRxDBContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "https://crm.advtis.com",
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "https://localhost:44354",
                IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(myRSA.ExportParameters(false))
            };
        });
        services.AddMvc();

    }
```

The JwtHelper.FromXml() method was adapted from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/874), because there is no way in .NET 2.0 to import or set parameters from XML within the RSA Provider, so that method parses the XML and sets the parameters like so:

```
public static void FromXml(this RSA rsa, string filepath)
    {
        RSAParameters parameters = new RSAParameters();

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(filepath);

        if (xmlDoc.DocumentElement.Name.Equals("RSAKeyValue"))
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                switch (node.Name)
                {
                    case "Modulus": parameters.Modulus = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                    case "Exponent": parameters.Exponent = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                    case "P": parameters.P = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                    case "Q": parameters.Q = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                    case "DP": parameters.DP = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                    case "DQ": parameters.DQ = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                    case "InverseQ": parameters.InverseQ = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                    case "D": parameters.D = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid XML RSA key.");
        }

        rsa.ImportParameters(parameters);
    }
```

So that's the gist of it.  Now I can issue JWTs from my PHP server to a client application.  Then I can send the JWTs over to my .NET Core 2.0 API to get access to endpoints protected by [Authorize] attribute.